# js can work under IE development tool only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, developer-tools

I'm maintaining an old intranet project, which have to work under IE7+, mostly IE11 with IE7 emulation mode. I found that sometimes the frontend scripts can work properly, and sometimes not. But thoses scripts can run 100% as expected under developer tool, WITHOUT any error or warning. That's annoying, I can't recommend to the users that if somethings when wrong then press F12 and then F5.

So, what can I do?

ps:

1. It's not about console not defined, I have fallback code (and a lot for other compatibility issues).
2. It's not about angularjs, I didn't use it.

== UPDATE ==

I'm trying to give an example of the symptom in textual:

1. fetch data from domino server by issue ajax call, and get the json result
2. processing the json result - sort the json result by date (including convert the domino specific json date format to datetime object)
3. write the result to a list in dom

The resulting list has two fields to display, the message body, and the processed date.

The message body is always display correctly, and sometimes the date field becomes 'null' (if one record become null, all records becomes null). The whole list can be display correctly when the debugger is on, and no any error produced.

Comment: So some scripts magically work or not work randomly, and yet for some reason work fine in developer tools? I don't see how that makes sense. Developer tools doesn't execute JS differently than the browser, it's just a debugging tool.

Comment: could it be a cache issue? i think some dev tools have the cache turned off by default so opening it up will cause the browser to  fetch everything again

Comment: From my past experience, you could either need to force redraw the UI. Or you have debugging code in the script somewhere. Search the code for any references to console and remove. Those are the two most likely scenarios I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the emulation options in the IE11 development tools, and sometimes (at least for me) the emulation settings you used last time will kick back in when you open the F12 tools back up.
Make sure the Document Mode setting in the Emulation tab is set to 7 (since you want your site to work in that mode.)

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to my problem, most of the pages has add the meta tag specifing the emulation mode as following:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />